# Centering Navigation Bar with CSS

Tags: html, css, navigation

I realize this question has been asked multiple times on this site, and many many others, probably too many times, I've tried many different solutions but haven't come up with one that fits, I'm trying to auto center with hidden overflow, any CSS masters willing to show me where I'm going wrong? I've been banging my head for awhile now. Here is my 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bsyxG/) Thank you for any assistance.

Here is my CSS since fiddle must be accompanied

CSS

```
 body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.navigation {
    position: relative;
    left: 15%;
    padding: 0 auto;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
.navigation li {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
.navigation li a {
    background: #262626;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 7px 8px 7px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #F2861D;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navigation li a:hover {
    color: #F2861D;
}
.navigation ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 -1px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #F2861D;
}
.navigation ul li {
    width: 150px;
    border-top: none;
}
.navigation ul a {
    display: block;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 8px 7px 13px 7px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #6B6B6B;
}
.navigation ul a:hover {
    color: #F2861D;
}
```

This is the closest I've gotten, I've attempted margin: 0 auto as well as margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto; but can't seem to get them to work.

Comment: I don't quite get what you require O.o please try to explain better

Comment: "I'm trying to auto center with hidden overflow"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this add a `.container{width:you want; margin:0 auto;}` then navigation bar in center.

http://jsfiddle.net/bsyxG/7/

CSS

```
 body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.container{
    width:1004px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
.navigation {
   text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
    list-style-type:none;

text-align:center;
}
.navigation li {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
.navigation li a {

    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 7px 8px 7px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #F2861D;
  background: #262626;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navigation li a:hover {
    color: #F2861D;
}
.navigation ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 -1px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #F2861D;
}
.navigation ul li {
    width: 150px;
    border-top: none;
}
.navigation ul a {
    display: block;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 8px 7px 13px 7px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #6B6B6B;
}
.navigation ul a:hover {
    color: #F2861D;
}
```

Comment: I would like you to provide some explanation, and than I will upvote :)

Comment: *try this*? you should explain what you modified in the existing code and what does that do/how it works...

Comment: Fags you truly are a CSS master, I'll try to work in the hidden overflow next, but the auto center was all I cared about, it did cross my mind having a div in a div but I'm still a beginner. Thanks again for your assistance!!!

Comment: Thanks @DrewG Please my answer you accept give 1 vote and welcome you

Answer (score 0):

**Use This:**

Changes are position:*absolute* from *relative* and margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.navigation {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 auto;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.navigation li {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
.navigation li a {
    background: #262626;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 7px 8px 7px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #F2861D;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navigation li a:hover {
    color: #F2861D;
}
.navigation ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 -1px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #F2861D;
}
.navigation ul li {
    width: 150px;
    border-top: none;
}
.navigation ul a {
    display: block;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 8px 7px 13px 7px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #6B6B6B;
}
.navigation ul a:hover {
    color: #F2861D;
}
```

Comment: I gave that a try Ahmed, but on my site, it just moves the Navbar to the far left, thank you though for your reply.

Comment: i tried it on jsfiddle and here is the link check it again:
http://jsfiddle.net/AhmedAlaaElDin/bsyxG/6/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left: 50%` `left:-50%` trick

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
}
.navigation {
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bsyxG/4/